# (DONE) Can we reopen: "how to deal with inter team work in a toxic team"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[How to deal with inter-team work in a toxic team?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/128977/how-to-deal-with-inter-team-work-in-a-toxic-team)

This has been edited down to a manageable size.  It's answerable now.

Comment: Voted to re-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the last vote. The question is now open.